# Why is there a 1MiB size limit for Firestore Documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, quota

The Firestore quotas page [says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas)

> Maximum size for a document   1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

Can anybody explain **the reason for having this limitation**?

I bet this is not a magic number but there is some logic/arguments behind this decision.

Moreover I wonder if this limit is ever going to change....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All limits are in place to prevent abuse of the system and prevent accidental inefficient use of it.  If you could have a document of unlimited size, certainly someone would take advantage of that to store infinite amounts of data in one document while avoiding the worst of billing.

If you feel that this limit is restrictive to your use case, [contact Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/).

Comment: I feel it's restrictive in my case indeed, that is because I need to store health data, and at this moment the 1MB is a very unfiting model if I dont use compression aka losing the benefits of the firestore. 

Would the support be able to help with this (perhaps increase the limit) 

Just to be clear, in the domain of activities with sampling 1s heart rate data, I cannot store more than 2 - 5h of data on one document for example (if not compressed)

Comment: Firestore may not be the best solution to your problem, then.

Comment: I agree, would you have any recommendation over that?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to get product recommendations.

Comment: Why not 10MB or 100MB?  A limit has to be placed somewhere, and 1MB is likely what was decided is reasonable for most applications.

Comment: and then why not 10KB or less it's still a magic number @Doug. Really.

Comment: All I can say is that you could accept it and work with it. And appreciate that it could keep you from shooting yourself in the foot in an expensive way.

Comment: I agree it's difficult to decide a default value but more relaxed limits such as what SQL databases or Mongo DB have would be preferred. One possible solution would be to let the dev decide the limit of document size in each collection but if that's too complex, a more relaxed limit will definitely help a lot of developers. Generally when we use a SQL database, we don't think about limit of a row but 1 MB is low enough to make devs concerned.